# confirm() function not defined in Javascript program

Tags: javascript, node.js, confirm

I am new to Javascript so forgive me if my query is too trivial. I am writing a simple program using the function "confirm()". Here it is:

```
if (confirm("Are you xyz?"))
{
console.log("Hello xyz, how are you?");
} else {
console.log("Then what is your name?");
}
```

But on running this I get the error: **confirm is not defined**. Do I need to install or call a package to make this confirm() function defined?

Comment: are you running this code in nodejs ?

Comment: @BrightFaith Yes

Comment: Node.js doesn't have a `confirm` function. That's a function provided by web browsers (which you should avoid even there).

Comment: nodejs runs on server , confirm is client-side function , runs on window

Comment: Okk.. So what is the alternative here?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Why confirm function should be avoided on web browsers?

Comment: you get data from user with inputs , you need to learn nodejs request/response and much more

Comment: @Dark_Knight - Because it blocks the UI thread. Instead, use the DOM.

Comment: @Dark_Knight not very user friendly. You cannot customize how it looks to match your style, you cannot translate it to offer proper options to users, you cannot make it show different options. It also blocks, so you cannot run other stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a very important difference between browser javascript and node.js. Browsers have a `confirm` function, while node does not. If you want to do something similar, you can use the readline module.

```js
const readline = require("readline");
const interface = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});
interface.question("Are you xyz? (y/n) ", function(ans) {
    if (ans == "y" || ans == "yes") {
        console.log("Hello there xyz.");
    } else {
        console.log("So what is your name?");
    }
    // pause the interface so the program can exit
    interface.pause();
});
```